# Why does this value in my model return null when used in my controller? (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

within my model i have a bool value called itemCheck:

```
public class Item
    {       
        public Array userDataItems { get; set; }

        public char[] delimiterChar { get; set; }

        public bool itemCheck { get; set; }

    }
```

My viewModel, linking the item model to the controller:

```
public class CategoryItemViewModel
    {
        public Item ItemList { get; set; }

        public Category CategoryList { get; set; }
    }
```

Which i then initialize within my main controller as false:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            CategoryItemViewModel CIVM = new CategoryItemViewModel();
            CIVM.ItemList = GetItemModel();
            CIVM.CategoryList = GetCategoryModel();
            return View(CIVM);
        }

 public Item GetItemModel()
        {
            var dataFileItems = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Item.txt");

            Item iModel = new Item()
            {
                userDataItems = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dataFileItems), //Items Text File
                delimiterChar = new[] { ',' },
                itemCheck = false,
            };

            return iModel;
        }
```

Then i use it in my view as the bool value to indicate whether a checkbox is ticked or not :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Items", "Items", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formFieldTwo" }))
        {
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ItemList.itemCheck, false)
        }
```

And lastly i try to access this variable 'itemCheck' which should be set to 'false' within my ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Items(string ItemDescription, CategoryItemViewModel m)
        {

            bool originalValue = m.ItemList.itemCheck;

            var FkFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ForeignKeyValue.txt");

            var Fk = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FkFile);

            var dataFileItems = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Item.txt");

            var numberOfLinesItems = System.IO.File.ReadLines(dataFileItems).Count();

            var textFileDataItems = ItemDescription + "," + numberOfLinesItems + "," + Fk + "," + originalValue + Environment.NewLine;

            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(dataFileItems, textFileDataItems);

            return View();
        }
```

However, i get the following error on the line 'bool originalValue = m.ItemList.itemCheck;' :

" System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' "

I fail to understand why my program is giving me this error?

Comment: What is `ItemList` in the statement `m=>m.ItemList.itemCheck`?  Your model shows that the property containing `itemCheck` is called `iModel`.  Shouldn't this be `m=>m.iModel.itemCheck`?  You're missing a piece of the puzzle in your code examples.  I would wager you are sending a list of these `Items` to the view and trying to use the `Html` editors for each item in the list.  There are other ways that you have to use to access the properties of a collection of items in a view model like you are wanting.

Comment: Apologies, i have uploaded another part to my models in the question, the reason i have done this is to have the ability to use variables from multiple models within a single view.

Comment: @Tommy i have updated my question with hopefully what is required for you to see what is going on. I apologize if i am a bit uncertain of any of your suggestions. ASP.NET and MVC are both very new concepts to me.

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ItemList.itemCheck, false)
```

To :

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.ItemList.itemCheck, false)
```

Comment: This unfortunately didn't seem to change anything for me. I am still getting a null reference exception. It seems as thou there is a missing link to the actual variable. The reference is obviously not picking up 'itemCheck' within my viewModel.

Comment: debug your code to see if m and ItemList both have value or not? first you need to find the null source.